# Git version bump error

Tags: git, sinatra

When I tried to run my sinatra app, I got this error:

```
 C:\Users\A2\Desktop\freetouring_v2>rackup -p 4444
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/git-version-bump-0.15.1/lib/git-version-b
ump.rb:299:in `gem_version': GVB.version(false) failed; perhaps you need to inst
all git? (GitVersionBump::VersionUnobtainable)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/git-version-bump-0.15.1/lib/
git-version-bump.rb:37:in `version'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/git-version-bump-0.15.1/lib/
git-version-bump/version.rb:2:in `<module:GitVersionBump>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/git-version-bump-0.15.1/lib/
git-version-bump/version.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/backports-3.6.7/lib/backport
s/std_lib.rb:9:in `require'
```

Problem seems to be Git related. So, can anyone explain to me where exactly is the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Considering how [`lib/git-version-bump.rb#L233-L237`](https://github.com/mpalmer/git-version-bump/blob/e6979908c92f91f1fb869cef100f45a506de67da/lib/git-version-bump.rb#L233-L237) determines if git is available or not, it seems you just to make sure that git is in your PATH.

```rb
def self.git_available?
    system("git --version >/dev/null 2>&1")

    $? == 0
end
```

Check if echo `%PATH%` reference your git installation folder.
You can install git by simply unzipping the [`PortableGit-2.7.3-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.3.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.3-64-bit.7z.exe) archive.

Comment: I have Git Installed, this is my echo %PATH%:
/*C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Win
dows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\
Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin*/

But I still get the error.

Comment: @1suli0 you need to have ``C:\Program Files\Git\bin\`` in your `%PATH%`, *not* `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`

Comment: @1suli0 if you type `git --version` in a CMD session, what is the output?

Comment: This is the output:
git version 2.7.3.windows.1

Comment: would love a solution to this, im experiencing the same problem with rackup giving me a git error, and i have included all the correct path variables, my git version is 2.8.0.windows.1

Comment: @alilland does the issue persists with Git 2.11? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Git [https://git-scm.com/downloads]
2. Install Git.
3. Go to MyComputer >right click >Advance system setting >Environment Variables > System Variables > Path > C:\Program Files\Git\bin (address where it's installed).
4. Open cmd and type

> git --verison

It will give you version of git which is installed on your system.

I hope it works.